# SSRS engine

Tags: reporting-services

This is regarding SSRS engine. For my project we are not going to buy SQL server software. Instead of what I just want to know, is there any posibility to use only SSRS engine. So that I can have the ref. (DLL) And then I can use wherever I want.

Please help on this.

Comment: Do you really believe that by typing in capitals it makes people more likely to answer your question?

Comment: don't write in all uppercase, it's rude!  It means you are YELLING your question

Comment: Hi, I am a nice guy and turned your shouting down. Please do it yourself next time you ask a question.

Comment: @Gamecat you are WAY too kind.

Answer (score 4):

If we don't consider the technical aspects of getting SSRS to run without SQL Server, you still need SQL Server for the license. SSRS is an integrated part of SQL Server, not a standalone component.

So no, without buying SQL Server licenses, you cannot use SSRS, even if you were technically able to do it, which I doubt anyway.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server Express, the free one, comes with Reporting Services.  No need to shell out for a full blown SQL Server.

http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/express.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server Reporting services engine is not just a dll. So it will be not just as simple as adding a ref.

You typically have to deploy reports to a webserver and invoke the reports though there.

I'd advise you to look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Reporting_Services

Answer (score 0):

You can create local reports that are not stored in a database if that's what you mean.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms252067(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

SSRS needs SQL Server as the ReportServer and ReportServerTempDB databases must be hosted on SQL Server. SQL Agent is also used by the SSRS Service:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156421.aspx

You could try PowerBI as an alternative solution for your project if you are not going to purchase SQL Server software licenses:
https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create local reports (.RDLC) using BIDS in visual studio. To render these reports, you need to write code to pass parameters and datasets values. You need to add reference of Report Viewer and use LocalReport to call Render method. It will return you byte array of rendered report.

```
            using (Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms.LocalReport report = new LocalReport())
            {
                string appPath = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

                report.ReportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "Reports", RDLName.ToString());

                foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> dataSource in ReportDataSource)
                {
                    report.DataSources.Add(new ReportDataSource(dataSource.Key, dataSource.Value));
                }

                if (ReportParameters != null)
                {
                    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, object> parameter in ReportParameters)
                    {
                        report.SetParameters(new ReportParameter(parameter.Key, (parameter.Value == null ? null : parameter.Value.ToString())));
                    }
                }

                result = report.Render(Format);

                report.Dispose();


                return result;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

using the report viewer runtime
[download from microsoft](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/download/details.aspx?id=45496)
[tutorial to use it](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/607382/Running-a-RDL-RDLC-SQL-Report-in-ASP-NET-without-S)
you can render rdl files and rdlc files locally, you just have to execute the query yourself